# Django query slow relative to raw SQL

Tags: django

I use `matches.query.__format__('')` to print the raw SQL that a Django query will execute.

If I execute that query directly in `psql` it takes 5-10ms, while the Django query as timed below can take up 100ms the first time it's executed.

Losing 100ms is a lot (will have to run a second query - so that's 2 x 100ms - add in latency and users easily notice). Is this normal? Am I missing something?

```
def api(request):
    tag = request.GET.get('q', '')
    matches = Relationship.objects.filter(keyword=tag, count__gte=3).order_by('-count')[:30]

    print(matches.query.__format__('')) # get raw SQL query here

    start_time = time.time()
    print(matches) # lazy query executed here
    print("Time elapsed {0:0.1f}ms".format((time.time() - start_time) * 1000))

    mydict = serialize_matches(matches, tag)
    return JsonResponse(mydict)
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for the tips below. Django seems fine, it's the database that's slow after all. Some of my `psql` queries were very fast as results were already cached. There seems to be some caching even when `psql` is restarted, which can confuse performance tests.

Comment: Is request exected 100ms or just the query? Django could also use autocommit that run `start transaction` before the query, and `commit` after, check the postgres log if this is the only query being executed

Comment: There is a toll for creating model objects in the memory. Use a ["values" queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) and compare performance, for some large querysets it can speedup things a lot (and since you are just dumping the models as JSON it makes no sense to pay for model creation in memory).

Comment: @Andras consider creating an answer yourself if you have solved your own question, your finding will be useful for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Django is fine and it was my database that was slow. Some `psql` queries were fast only because **results were cached**. Note, there seems to be some caching even when `psql` is restarted.

So when you are testing the performance of your database make sure queries aren't cached.

It was **not necessary to use raw SQL queries** at the end as the Django ORM seems just fine in terms of performance.